# How to run test suite in python for flask framework and get code coverage?

Tags: python

I want to run the test cases for my python code where am using flask framework.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Am I right that you already have the test cases and can run them successfully but only code coverage is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this command to run the test suite in flask framework

**pytest --cov=src --cov-report=html**

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you've written the test cases in the first place. Happily, though, [Pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) tends to be able to run whatever at least close to standard tests you have, and `pytest-cov` adds coverage.

So, once you have `pytest` and `pytest-cov` installed, you can

```
pytest --cov . --cov-report term --cov-report html
```

and you'll get

- a report of coverage in the console
- a `htmlcov/` directory with pretty, colorful coverage information.

Answer (score 0):

If you've written your code as REST API. I would recommend pyresttest.
You can write your test cases as simple as this in a test.yaml file.

```
- test: # create entity by POST
    - name: "Create person"
    - url: "/api/person/"
    - method: "POST"
    - body: '{"first_name": "Ahmet","last_name": "Tatanga"}'
    - headers: {Content-Type: application/json}
```

Then you just run this test case by

```
pyresttest test.yaml
```

You can implement some validators for returned JSON. To learn more please check [here](https://github.com/svanoort/pyresttest).